# How to create an alias in Terminal to reach my server

Tags: terminal

I am trying to create an alias to reach our shared server at work. To find the server using manual terminal inputs I type the following separate inputs:

```
cd ..
cd ..
cd Volumes
cd Production
```

I want all of this to be one single alias in my .bash_profile

I tried the following which didn't work:

```
alias work="cd ~ cd .. cd .. cd Volumes cd Production"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alias needs to be a valid command. You forgot && between your commands:

```
alias work="cd ~ && cd .. && cd .. && cd Volumes && cd Production"
```

Or you could shorten it into one command using relative paths:

```
alias work="cd ~/../../Volumes/Production"
```